# How can I create a nested object representation of a folder structure

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, recursion

So I need to get a **flat array** and a **nested object** that represents a folder structure. It does however need to filter out certain folder that do not have certain files (`FILE.txt`) inside of them and ignore files all together.

Consider these files:

```
.
├── folder0                # not this folder
│   ├── FILE.txt           # <- here  
│   ├── some.other
│   └── more.files
├── stuff                  # not this folder
│   ├── some.other
│   └── more.files
└── folder1
    ├── FILE.txt           # <- here
    ├── subfolder1
    │   ├── FILE.txt       # <- here
    │   ├── some.other
    │   └── more.files
    ├── subfolder2
    │   └── FILE.txt       # <- here
    └── subfolder3
        ├── FILE.txt       # <- here
        ├── subsubfolder1
        │   ├── FILE.txt   # <- here
        │   ├── some.other
        │   └── more.files
        └── subsubfolder2
            └── FILE.txt   # <- here
```

**What I need is two things:**

**A flat array** with paths to each folder with the `FILE.txt` inside of it:

```
[
  "folder0",
  "folder1",
  "folder1/subfolder1",
  "folder1/subfolder2",
  "folder1/subfolder3",
  "folder1/subfolder3/subsubfolder1",
  "folder1/subfolder3/subsubfolder1"
]
```

**And a nested object** that represents the nesting of the folders:

```
{
  'folder0': 'folder0',
  'folder1': {
    'subfolder1': 'subfolder1',
    'subfolder2': 'subfolder2',
    'subfolder3': {
      'subsubfolder1': 'subsubfolder1',
      'subsubfolder2': 'subsubfolder2'
    }
  }
}
```

Now I got the first. Pretty simple recursive walk through the system:

```
const GetContent = ( folder, content = []) => {
  if( Fs.existsSync( folder ) ) {
    Fs.readdirSync( folder )
      .map(
        file => {
          if( Fs.statSync( Path.join( folder, file ) ).isDirectory() ) {
            const result = GetContent( Path.join( folder, file ), content );
            content = [ ...result ];
          }
          else {
            if( file === `${ SETTINGS.get().folder.index }.yml` ) {
              content.push( folder );
            }
          }
        }
      );

    return content;
  }
};
```

This code will give me the **flat array** and all is good.

### Question

- However how do it get to my **nested object**? I want to prevent accessing the filesystem twice.
- Should this be done as an extra function or inside the same as above to prevent yet another loop?

### What I tried

I have tried for way too long to get it in the same function somehow.
I then thought maybe I just convert the flat array into a nested object but boy my head hurts today. But the broken test below just won't do it. I think my head is blocked for today. Anyone help?

```
const ToDepth = ( items, result, iterator = 0 ) => {

  iterator ++;
  result[ items[ 0 ] ] = {};

  if( items.length > 1 ) {
    result[ items[ 0 ] ] = ToDepth( items.slice( 1 ), result[ items[ 0 ] ], iterator );
  }
  else {
    if( Object.keys( result[ items[ 0 ] ] ).length === 0 ) {
      result[ items[ 0 ] ] = items[ 0 ];
    }
  }

  return result;
}


const ToNested = ( element ) => {
  let result = {};

  element.map( ( item ) => {
    result = ToDepth( item.split('/'), result );
  });

  return result;
};

ToNested( flatArray );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on the code:

```js
const flat = [
  "folder0",
  "folder1",
  "folder1/subfolder1",
  "folder1/subfolder2",
  "folder1/subfolder3",
  "folder1/subfolder3/subsubfolder1",
  "folder1/subfolder3/subsubfolder2"
];
const nested = {};
const add = (source, target) => {
  const elements = source.split("/");
  const element = elements.shift();
  target[element] = target[element] || element;
  if (elements.length) {
    target[element] = typeof target[element] === "object" ? target[element] : {};
    add(elements.join("/"), target[element]);
  }
};

flat.forEach(item => add(item, nested));

console.log(nested);
```

Basically, it's a recursive function that adds consecutive parts of every element in the flat array to the target object, moving down the structure as needed. You could probably make this prettier. But it works and outputs what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks great, will test when I get to work in a minute. So you think it should be an extra function, an additional loop? Since I'm already iterating over the folders I'd rather have it inside the same look but I'm possibly making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I don't know whether it should be an extra function or not. I'm just offering one way of tackling the issue that works. You might end up finding a much better way :)